# How to use Flex CSS and simulate a rowspan 2 and colspan 2

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to build a responsive layout with  2 rows using divs .

I try this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/jiyanayayi/edit?html,css,output

The first row will have three cells, the last one (cell 3) must have a `rowspan = 2`

The second row (cell4) having a `colspan = 2` must be limited by the cell 3.

I tried the CSS below, but the `rowspan` atribute did not work.

How can I create this responsive layout format?

```
.row{
  display: flex;
}
.cell{
  flex: 1;
  background:#eee;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Cell 1 </div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 2 </div>
        <div class="cell rowspan2">Cell 3 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell colspan2">Cell 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is this supposed to look like?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Edit 2021** use the `grid` CSS part stand inside the `@supports` querie, unless you still need to supports some exotic browsers or very old ones. If you are not sure, you can use the [jsbin sample](https://jsbin.com/wexisiyamo/1/edit?html,css,output) *(also linked at the end of that answer)* within the browser you want to supports. - *jsbin should work and be live edited with old browsers, at least it does with IE11.*

`grid` placement options are [`grid-area`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-2/#source-independence) or [`grid-column` and `grid-row`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-2/#common-uses-numeric) ( *both links are about* Grid Layout Module Level 2 *from* W3C ). The code below uses `grid-area` and you will find the `grid-column` and `grid-row` syntax commented.

Also This is **not** a `table-layout` and Question/Answers here are **not** about HTML table.

**end edit**

---

you need to use also `flex` and **`flex-wrap`**:

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  border: solid;
}

.row {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.row:first-of-type {
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.row .rowspan2 {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.row div {
  border: solid;
  padding: 1em;
  flex: 1;
}

/* ============================================================== */
/* if display grid and contents is supported then you may use it  */
/* ============================================================== */
/*
@supports (display:grid) and (display:contents) {
  .table {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    grid-template-areas: "cell1 cell2 cell3 cell3" "cell4 cell4 cell3 cell3";
    border: solid;
  }
  .row {
    display: contents/* hide them in the structure. .row respective children become sibblings *//*
  }
  .row:first-child> :first-child {
    grid-area: cell1;
  }
  .row:first-child div {
    grid-area: cell2;
  }
  .row .cell.rowspan2 {
    grid-area: cell3;
    /*grid-row:span 2; no need if grid-template-area is complete*//*
  }
  div div {
    border: solid;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  .colspan2 {
    grid-area: cell4;
    /*grid-column : span 2; no need if grid-template-area is complete*//*
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 2</div>
    <div class="cell rowspan2">Cell 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell colspan2">Cell 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsbin updated with `@supports` uncommented : https://jsbin.com/wexisiyamo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @ÂngeloRigo I suggest you to go read a few tutorils about flexbox and have some fun playing around with it to fully understands what you can do with ;) (csstricks and codepen should make this easy )

Comment: I see a lot of white space from cell 3 to the top. Trying margin-top did not work . Any idea to make elements closer to the top on cell 3 ? to avoid much blank space betweeen cell3 and cell1 and cell 2?

Comment: @ÂngeloRigo well not sure i understand what you mean, there is only padding in those cells remove it :)

Comment: This version seems to result in Cells 3 and 4's position being swapped, versus what's described in the question. `.colspan2` is used in the markup but not in the styles...

Comment: @emyr the HTML structure was untouched and CSS grid was too less supported yet to be proposed but still, snippet could have been updated with display:grid to fit 100% to question ;)  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/peYBga _(display:contents involved to keep structure untouched experimental )_

Comment: @Jake colspan and rowspan are attributes only avalaible in th or td and there is no such equivalence in CSS. `span x` seems similar but only avalaible for a grid child , there is also `column-span` avalaible for column CSS in a few browsers. For the position of element, with grid/ flex there is `order` , for grid `grid-area` `grid-column`and `grid-row` .  -/- For a real table, there is nothing alike a real table . **feel free to add an answer showing us that colspan and rowspan exists in CSS**

Comment: I get that. But in a table, colspan spans columns: horizontal span across multiple columns. It looks your definition of colspan is a vertical span across multiple rows.

Comment: @Jake yes, but that is not the subject of the question, the op knew it and was looking for a CSS alternative which can only be a mimic, , there is no table involved here , just display trying to using its algorithm. not even avalaible from `display:table` ;)

Comment: @jake , sorry to insist on your comment. You cannot mistake HTML attributes and CSS rules. if the question was how can i mimic attribute required, would you propose also  `.required` class and link to the HTML attribute required ? Obviously not , because a div is not an imput, you could propose javascript to propose to mimic such a behavior or tell to use an input. CSS is only about styling.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all. Your comparison to the HTML attribute required is a complete strawman. There is a system in place for how to span columns. You span... the columns. It isn't about matching a spec. Your colspan does not span columns. It spans rows. It isn't about a spec, it is about common sense. colspan should span the columns, not the rows.

Comment: OK, tell us how you apply  your `.colspan` or `.rowspan` class on a div you mentionned in your comment, a div actually being à flex child ? Or did you misread the question and answer here? Or maybe it is just about a joke played on Me? ;) @jake